# HAL Modules not built in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build android 4.3.1 from AOSP for a device (Samsung Galaxy TAB 2 7.0) . The ota package was compiled without problem but when I flash it My tablet stuck on black screen.When i checked my output system folder I found that The shared libraries located in system/lib/hw wasn't compiled during the build process . I have only many "name.default.so" . However the different HAL Libs folder are in my device tree  I have declared them in my device.mk to be built.

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES := \
        audio.primary.piranha \
        audio.a2dp.default \
    camera.piranha \
    hwcomposer.piranha \
    power.piranha \
    lights.piranha
```

I am forced to use commands like "make audio.primary.piranha" to built them separately.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you sure that there's no `PRODUCT_PACKAGES :=` after the one you added?

Answer (score 0):

There is :

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES := \
    libion \
    Gallery2 \
    librs_jni \
    com.android.future.usb.accessory
```